# Microsoft Edge Application Cache Limit

Tags: caching, microsoft-edge, html5-appcache

Can anyone find any documentation on Microsoft Edge's Application Cache (AppCache or Offline Cache) download limit?  I've spent a long time looking around online but with no luck.

I ran http://www.der-schepp.de/appcache-default-size/ and came up with 20MB, but can't find any documentation on it from Microsoft or any other 3rd party.  I guess I'm just looking for some confirmation that 20MB is the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is 10 MB or 50 MB depending on volume size.

This is related to *WebView* user control, but because the *WebView* is using EdgeHTML I beleive the limit is the same for the Edge browser.

See [webview element documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5000527) for more details.